# Rails 4 - CRUD error after migrating to Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've just migrated my database from sqlite to postgresql and I'm encountering some issue with destroy action that was working fine when database was sqlite.

Requested parameter contains id value and this id exists in the database
and it will destroy just fine although I see this error screen.
I'm not sure what this is complaining about.

[image: error]

**controller**

```
before_action :find_recipe, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

...

def destroy
  Recipe.destroy(params[:id])
  redirect_to :back, notice: "Recipe successfully deleted"
end

private
  def find_recipe
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error does not appear related to the destroy at all, it appears to be attempting to show the record.  Most likely you redirected back to the record's show page after destroying it.

Flow:

- /show/5 (you click destroy)
- /destroy/5 (destroys record)
- /show/5 (via redirect_to :back, but the ID no longer exists)

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering why it would complain about show action. I had `redirect_to :back` in destroy action which I shouldn't have. It's all good now!